# Replacing SQLite file with downloaded one from server. iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, sqlite

Is it possible to replace (or delete) a sqlite database with a new sqlite file I prepare on a server? I would like to prepare database on my server using php and send it to my device in which it replaces the current db and uses the new database. I am using SQLite with a FMDB wrapper. I am not using core data. If is possible what would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the new sqlite file.

```
[db close]
```

You have to close the current Connection to your database and if you want to you have to replace the old file with the new. You can use the path to the new file without removing the old one.

then open the connection to the new file

```
db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/pathToNewDBFile/new.sqlite"];
```